# htaccess rewrite for known URL and query string

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, query-string

Have been struggling with a 301 redirect issue and cannot see the wood for the trees. Really hope someone can assist.

I have over 400 old urls that we need to redirect to a new urls. I have however modified the htaccess to create a clean url on the new site and am not sure if this is causing an issue or if I am doing something else wrong.

To clean urls in the new site I have added the following to the htaccess fle:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+) category?cat=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

This is so that instead of `www.mysite/category?cat=1`  I can have `www.mysite/1` and-add-other-information

I am now trying to do the redirects for the 400 urls such as:

```
 RewriteRule ^category?cat=1 1/and-add-other-information [R=301,NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^category?cat=2 1/and-different-information [R=301,NC,L,QSA].
```

I know the `L` flag makes a difference and have tried this with and without.

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

QueryString isn't part of match in pattern of a RewriteRule. 
You need to use `RewriteCond` directive and match against `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable like the following :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cat=1$
RewriteRule ^category$ /and-add-other-information? [R=301,NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sadly, I do not think I made it as clear as I should have. 
I have an old set of urls that need to be 301 redirects with additional information not present in the old url. 
OLD url category?cat=1 
NEW url /1/and-then-info-related-to-the-get.


I have a list as such:
category?cat=1 replace with url /1/this-items-name-is-X.
category?cat=2 replace with  url /2/ this-service-name-is-Y.
category?cat=3 replace with  url /3/ this-items-name-is-Z.